# Is is possible to use my own derived AppBuilder class with OWIN and Katana

Tags: c#, owin

I am investigating ways to use a DI container with OWIN. I am wondering if you can supply your own class that derives from `Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder`

Basically when the method

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```

Is called in my startup class I would like to have access to the container. I would like to register my middleware components with the container so they can have additional dependencies. The container is registered in the Global.asax.cs file in the application. I could make it a static so I could reference it from anywhere, but I don't want to do that.

Can you specify your own implementation of AppBuilder?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am wondering the same thing...

Comment: No I did not, I hate construction of important functions by attributes. I have got to go back and look at it before the end of April though, I'll report back if I find anything good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After far, far, far too much ILSpying:

```
var options = new StartOptions();
options.Settings["Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Builder.IAppBuilderFactory"] = "MyNamespace.MyAppBuilderFactory,My.Assembly.Name";

var webServer = Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(options);

public class MyAppBuilderFactory : IAppBuilderFactory
{
    public IAppBuilder Create()
    {
        return new MyAppBuilder();
    }
}
```